# Access class of other OSGi bundle

Tags: osgi, bundle

My project has two bundles, lets say `Bundle A` and `Bundle B`.

Now `Bundle A` needs to access a class from `Bundle B`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Add the dependency of bundle B to the Manifest of bundle A:  `Require-Bundle: bundle-id-of-bundle-A`
2. Import the package of the wanted class in the Manifest of bundle A: `Import-Package: package.of.your.class`

In both situations, you need to export the package that contains your class in bundle B: `Export-Package: package.of.your.class`

Also, here's a good intro:
http://ctpjava.blogspot.com/2010/09/introduction-to-osgi.html

Comment: As @thobens states there are two ways; but Require-Bundle is bad practice, you should only use Import-Package - in OSGi the package is the unit of modularity and this is what you should depend on, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865819/when-should-i-use-import-package-and-when-should-i-use-require-bundle, http://njbartlett.name/2011/02/09/uses-constraints.html and http://www.osgi.org/blog/2011/05/unbearable-lightness-of-jigsaw.html for more indepth discussions of why Require-Bundle is bad.

Answer (score 1):

As @earcam wrote, it is strongly recommended to use `Import-Package:`.

Also, always add a version to the exported package in bundle B - this is good practice that you will appreciate later when you create the next version of bundles A and B.