# Eclipse cannot resolve classes from another project in the workspace

Tags: eclipse, osgi, eclipse-rcp, manifest, buildpath

I am facing an issue that is driving me crazy in here. I have a project in my workspace that exports a package in it's manifest file like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Service
Bundle-SymbolicName: br.unicamp.cepetro.unisim.mero.service
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Vendor: Unisim
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Export-Package: br.unicamp.cepetro.unisim.mero.service
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.swt;bundle-version="3.6.0",
 org.eclipse.equinox.common;bundle-version="3.6.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.services;bundle-version="0.9.1",
 org.eclipse.osgi;bundle-version="3.6.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts;bundle-version="0.9.0",
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.8.101"
Import-Package: javax.inject;version="1.0.0"
```

The funny thing is: I have one project that references classes from the exported package just fine, but the other one does not. The build path is apparently ok, eclipse even put the imports automatically on save actions but it gets highlighted in red saying "import XXX cannot be resolved". I've already tried cleaning the projects, re-creating the project, change from package-import to bundle import but with no success.

The manifest for the one that works is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Navigator
Bundle-SymbolicName: br.unicamp.cepetro.unisim.mero.navigator;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.8.101",
 org.eclipse.swt;bundle-version="3.102.1",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench;bundle-version="1.0.1",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.di;bundle-version="1.3.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.services;bundle-version="1.0.1",
 org.eclipse.jface;bundle-version="3.9.1",
 org.eclipse.equinox.common;bundle-version="3.6.200",
 org.eclipse.osgi;bundle-version="3.9.1",
 org.eclipse.core.databinding;bundle-version="1.4.1",
 org.eclipse.jface.databinding;bundle-version="1.6.200",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.commands;bundle-version="0.10.2",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts;bundle-version="1.3.1",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.services;bundle-version="1.1.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench,
 org.eclipse.emf.common,
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore;bundle-version="2.9.1",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt;bundle-version="0.12.1"
Import-Package: br.unicamp.cepetro.unisim.mero.model.mero,
 br.unicamp.cepetro.unisim.mero.service,
 javax.annotation;version="1.1.0",
 javax.inject;version="1.0.0"
Service-Component: OSGI-INF/serviceRegistryComponent.xml
```

The manifest for the one that does not is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Mero
Bundle-SymbolicName: br.unicamp.cepetro.unisim.mero;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Vendor: Unisim
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt;bundle-version="0.12.1",
 org.eclipse.equinox.app;bundle-version="1.3.100",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme;bundle-version="0.9.100",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.di;bundle-version="1.3.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench;bundle-version="1.0.1",
 br.unicamp.cepetro.unisim.mero.model;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.8.101",
 org.eclipse.equinox.common;bundle-version="3.6.200",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.services;bundle-version="1.0.1",
 org.eclipse.jface;bundle-version="3.9.1",
 org.eclipse.core.jobs;bundle-version="3.5.300",
 br.unicamp.cepetro.unisim.mero.service;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 org.eclipse.osgi;bundle-version="3.9.1",
 org.eclipse.core.runtime;bundle-version="3.9.0",
 org.eclipse.core.filesystem;bundle-version="1.4.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.services;bundle-version="1.1.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts;bundle-version="1.3.1",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench;bundle-version="1.0.1",
 br.unicamp.cepetro.unisim.mero.i18n,
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.di;bundle-version="1.0.0"
Service-Component: OSGI-INF/serviceRegistryComponent.xml, OSGI-INF/defaultProjectService.xml, OSGI-INF/eclipseProjectImporterService.xml, OSGI-INF/imageServiceFunction.xml, OSGI-INF/nlsLookupFactoryService.xml
 OSGI-INF/defaultProjectService.xml
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Import-Package: javax.inject;version="1.0.0"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In the bundle that is resolving correctly, you've specified an `Import-Pacakge` for the service package, but in the one that isn't working you've specified a dependency on the service bundle (via `Require-Bundle`). See [When should I use Import-Package and when should I use Require-Bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865819/when-should-i-use-import-package-and-when-should-i-use-require-bundle) for some discussion about the differences.

I suspect the reason you are not getting correct resolution in the second bundle is because the version you've specified is `1.0.0` but the service bundle's actual declared version is `1.0`.

Comment: Changed to import-package but the error still happens :(