# Which packages need to be imported when extending AbstractTextEditor?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am writing an Eclipse editor plugin and my editor class extends `AbstractTextEditor`. However, I get the error: "The hierarchy of the type MyTextEditor is inconsistent".

Hence, I am wondering whether I forgot some package import. I imported the packages of `AbstractTextEditor`'s parent classes, but the error remains. I guess I either forgot a package or the error is caused by something else... These are the packages I imported so far:

```
org.eclipse.ui
org.eclipse.ui.part
org.eclipse.ui.texteditor
```

Comment: As long as you write Eclipse plug-ins (as opposed to pure OSGi bundles), why don't you use `Require-Bundle` to specify the dependencies? The AbstractTextEditor is in bundle `o.e.ui.workbench.texteditor` and you'll likely need `o.e.ui`, `o.e.editors`, `o.e.jface.text` (try one by one)

Comment: Yes, that worked :) (org.eclipse.core.runtime is needed as well). Could you write this as an answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you write Eclipse plug-ins (as opposed to pure OSGi bundles), you can as well use `Require-Bundle` to specify the dependencies.

In general, it is [much better to express dependencies using `Import-Package`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865819/when-should-i-use-import-package-and-when-should-i-use-require-bundle). However in an Eclipse plug-in setting there is usually no alternate bundle that might provide the the desired API, plus PDE lacks decent support for packages first development.

The `AbstractTextEditor` is in bundle

- `org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor` and you'll likely also need
- `org.eclipse.ui`
- `org.eclipse.editors`
- `org.eclipse.jface.text`
- `org.eclipse.core.runtime`.