# p2-maven-plugin -- bundle conflicts with other existing bundle

Tags: eclipse, maven, osgi, p2, bnd

I’m starting to use the **[p2-maven-plugin](https://github.com/reficio/p2-maven-plugin)** in order to integrate non-OSGi JARs into our project in a (hopefully) convenient manner.

I have an artifact which I want to OSGi-ify, called `com.thirdparty.artifact`. I’m current using p2-maven-plugin’s [standard configuration](https://github.com/reficio/p2-maven-plugin#how-to-use-it-in-2-minutes), and I list my artifact in the `pom.xml` like so:

```
<artifact><id>com.thirdparty:artifact:1.2.3</id></artifact>
```

This artifact has a transitive dependency called `com.thirdparty:library:2.5`, which exports a package `com.thirdparty.library` which is in turn imported by `com.thirdparty:artifact`. When I run `mvn p2:site`, I get a P2 site which contains `com.thirdparty:artifact:1.2.3` and `com.thirdparty:library:2.5` -- all fine so far.

Now, things are turning messy. My existing target platform already contains an artifact called `com.othervendor:library` (different vendor, it’s there and I cannot change that), which **also** exports the very same package `com.thirdparty.library` (but an entirely different version).

At runtime, the OSGi/Eclipse black magic (which I’ll probably never fully understand) tries to resolve `com.thirdparty:artifact`’s dependency on the package `com.thirdparty.library` using the `com.othervendor:library` and **not** my provided `com.thirdparty:library:2.5` -- and I’m obviously in trouble. Here’s a visualization of my situation:

[image: StaightFromDependencyHell]

Being absolutely no OSGi rocket scientist, my first idea was to inspect the `MANIFEST.MF` in `com.thirdparty:artifact`. Beside others, this shows the following:

```
Import-Package: com.thirdparty.library
```

So, this obviously just tells `com.thirdparty:artifact` to import this package from **some** bundle, and OSGi/Eclipse thinks “okay, `com.othervendor:library` is more adequate than `com.thirdparty:library`”.

There seem to be [two methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865819/when-should-i-use-import-package-and-when-should-i-use-require-bundle) of narrowing down the dependencies to actually use. However: I’m not sure (a) how to integrate them into my `p2-maven-plugin` workflow, and (b) I do not understand why `p2-maven-plugin` does not automatically require the concrete package version in the `Import-Package` directive (this information is after all already specified in the source `pom.xml`).

Probably I’m not seeing the forest for the trees here. So any general advice beside my questions above is very welcome!

---

**[edit]** Here’s my `pom.xml` (the concrete library which I’m about to OSGi-ify is Selenium):

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.example.p2dependencies</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.reficio</groupId>
        <artifactId>p2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <configuration>
              <artifacts>
                <artifact><id>org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.4.0</id></artifact>
              </artifacts>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

---

**[edit2]** Problem seems to be solved, it seems, the issue was an additional package which was only exported by `com.othervendor:library`.

Comment: Can you show pom file..?

Comment: @khmarbaise Sure ... edited question.